# Pytorch Lightening not using all resources

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, pytorch-lightning, distributed-training, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

I am running the [lab 1](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-distributed-training-workshop/blob/main/1_data_parallel/Lab_1.ipynb) example as it is. Everything goes fine and training succeeds. But when I check the training logs, Its is all happening on [1,mpirank:0,algo-1]. I am passing the instance_count as two and can see there are two hosts [algo-1 and algo-2]. Each has 8 gpu on each so the mpirank goes from 0-15, but all training logs have just [1,mpirank:0,algo-1].
Ideally it mpi rank should go from 0-15 and use both algo-1 and algo-2.
Below is the sample from log.

Could something be wroung be congiguration?

```
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 0:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00,  6.54it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 1113.73it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 0: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 12.33it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 0: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 12.33it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 0: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 12.10it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015                                                            #033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 0: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 12.05it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 0:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]        #015Epoch 1:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 1:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 35.14it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 1:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00,  9.28it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 1333.22it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 1: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 17.19it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 1: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 17.18it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.166]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 1: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 16.85it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.206]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015                                                            [1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 1: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 16.77it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.206]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 1:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.206]        #015Epoch 2:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.206]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 2:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 34.22it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.206]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 2:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 33.82it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.206]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 1283.05it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 2: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 52.55it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.206]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 2: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 47.22it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.246]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015                                                            #033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 2: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 46.59it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.246]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 2:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.246]        #015Epoch 3:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.246]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 3:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 35.53it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.246]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 3:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 34.17it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.246]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s][1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 1230.36it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 3: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 52.96it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.246]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 3: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 47.93it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.277][1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015                                                            #033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 3: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 47.29it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.277]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 3:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.277]        #015Epoch 4:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.277]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 4:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 35.43it/s, loss=2.29, v_num=0, val_acc=0.277]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 4:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 34.41it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.277]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 1197.69it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 4: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 52.35it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.277]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 4: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 48.23it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.305]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015                                                            #033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 4: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 47.55it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.305]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 4:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.305]        #015Epoch 5:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.305]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 5:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 35.41it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.305]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 5:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 34.12it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.305]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation DataLoader 0: 100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 1276.42it/s]#033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 5: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 52.82it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.305]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 5: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 48.07it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.333]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015                                                            #033[A
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 5: 100% 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 47.45it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.333]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 5:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.333]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 6:   0% 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.333]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 6:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 35.15it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.333]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Epoch 6:  50% 1/2 [00:00<00:00, 34.69it/s, loss=2.28, v_num=0, val_acc=0.333]
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:#015Validation: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]#033[A
```

It should use all resouces, something like.

```
[1,mpirank:0,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:1,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:2,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:3,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:4,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:5,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:6,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:7,algo-1]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:8,algo-2]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:9,algo-2]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:10,algo-2]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:11,algo-2]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:12,algo-2]<stdout>:
[1,mpirank:13,algo-2]<stdout>:
```

Comment: Chances are that the logging is only happening in rank zero. Did you check the GPU utilization. Try setting this parameter when using self.log to explicitly specific not to log on rank zero. rank_zero_only = False

Comment: Do you have any link/blog/article I can refer to for this please.

Comment: In the code you are referring just try adding an another attribute to the log statements something like this and re run. 
self.log("val_acc", torch.stack(outputs).mean(), prog_bar=True,rank_zero_only=False)

Comment: I tried adding above line. Output remains the same. It is still on mpi 0 only.

Comment: Actually this is how self.log works.
https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/discussions/6501